# Comparing Iterable with a List throws an NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I want to compare an `Iterable<Class>` with an `List<Class>`.

My iterable method is:

```
public Iterable<Class> findAll(final List<Long> idList) {
        final List<Class> result = new LinkedList<Class>();
        final List<List<Long>> partitions = ListUtils.partition(idList, 999);
        partitions.forEach(partition -> Iterables.addAll(result, this.repository.findAll(partition)));
        return result;
    }
```

where it ids is just a list of ids: `List<Long> idList = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L);`

I define the iterable like this:
`Iterable<Class> actual = service.findAll(ids)`

I have an  and an  `List<Class> expected= new LinkedList<Class>();`
Where I add the same values as in the iterable.

The value of the Iterable is and the List are the same:

```
[Class(id=1, name=null, action=null, data=null) Class(id=2, name=null, action=null, data=null)]
[Class(id=1, name=null, action=null, data=null), Class(id=2, name=null, action=null, data=null)]
```

When I compare them with `asserEquals(expected, actual)` I get an **NullPointerException.** 
I know they have different types, but they have the same values. Why can't I compare them? 
I used even .equals() just to check and I still get an NPE.

Then I tried to get just the first values

```
 assertEquals(expected.get(0), result.iterator().next());
```

and I still get an NPE.

I checked the Iterable Documentation and is is written that iterator() throws and NPE.

```
Iterator<T> iterator();

    /**
     * Performs the given action for each element of the {@code Iterable}
     * until all elements have been processed or the action throws an
     * exception.  Unless otherwise specified by the implementing class,
     * actions are performed in the order of iteration (if an iteration order
     * is specified).  Exceptions thrown by the action are relayed to the
     * caller.
     *
     * @implSpec
     * <p>The default implementation behaves as if:
     * <pre>{@code
     *     for (T t : this)
     *         action.accept(t);
     * }</pre>
     *
     * @param action The action to be performed for each element
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified action is null
     * @since 1.8
     */
```

Does this mean that I have to compare the first element of the iterator with that of the list. Then the second element of the iterator with the second element of the list? I'm not sure here.

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.sbb.project.model.Class.equals(Class.java:224)
    at java.util.AbstractList.equals(AbstractList.java:523)
    at org.junit.Assert.isEquals(Assert.java:131)
    at org.junit.Assert.equalsRegardingNull(Assert.java:127)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:111)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at ch.sbb.project.service.ServiceTest.findAll(ServiceTest.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Are they (either of them) empty?

Comment: Why are you using `Iterable` rather than `List`, which is the common type here?

Comment: @UlanMukhamedyanov no they are not empty

Comment: @RealSkeptic because I have a method which returns an Iterable and I'm trying to test that method

Comment: Then your iterable is not initialized to `new LinkedList()...` but rather it's the result of a method? Please [edit] your question and include enough code for us to see what you are really doing.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ok I will do that now

Comment: I'm guessing that you're getting a null returned for `actual`

Comment: @DonHosek Yes I think so too. I think it is the `iterator()` method which throws that one. Even though I'm not using the `iterator()` method...

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @Lesiak I posted it

Comment: @dernor00 the problem is in the wrong implementation of equals in your `Class` class. Again, share it if you need more help. Probably you are comparing two null fields in a wrong way